# how to declare exception in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

*Oracle*:

```
DECLARE 
  Child_rec_exception EXCEPTION; 
  PRAGMA 
   EXCEPTION_INIT (Child_rec_exception, -2292); 
BEGIN 
  Delete FROM product where product_id= 104; 
EXCEPTION 
   WHEN Child_rec_exception 
   THEN Dbms_output.put_line('Child records are present for this product_id.'); 
END;
```

what is the equivalent in PostgreSQL?

Comment: You don't need to declare them in PostgreSQL. You can [trap errors](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-ERROR-TRAPPING) by their condition name, category name, SQLSTATE or the special `OTHERS`. [A full list of error names & codes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/errcodes-appendix.html)